# Immigration time at Houston airport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, iah

I am travelling from Mumbai to Lafayette via Munich-Houston. As Houston will be my first port of entry in US, I will have to go through immigration. The layover time at Houston airport is one and half hours. Will I be able to go through immigration in such a short time and board my connecting flight to Lafayette?

Comment: Is this on a through ticket, or did you buy your India-Houston and Houston-Lafayette tickets separately?

Comment: I had bought a single ticket from Lufthansa from Mumbai to Lafayette

Comment: I had booked the ticket from Lufthansa's website

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost certainly yes.

If you look up [average wait times](http://awt.cbp.gov/) at IAH you will see they are typically 10-15 minutes throughout most of the day, though in some cases (like very early morning) can be much longer.

If the airline booked this all on one ticket, then they think you can make the connection, and they are responsible to put you on a later flight if you are delayed in immigration.

Note that these are security wait times, when you get to the US you will have to collect your baggage first before clearing customs; this can take time as well.

Comment: They know you're coming and depending on the airline, if enough people are stuck in customs, they'll delay the flight.

Comment: I do remember Houston immigration being speedy, but those numbers seem almost too good, just me ?

Comment: @Blackbird57 DHS has done a lot of work in the past couple of years to speed up immigration, not only at IAH but at most other US airports. One of the big things is that repeat VWP visitors can now use automated passport kiosks. That alone helped cut the lines quite a bit. And of course US and Canadian citizens can do passport control from their smartphones.

Comment: @MichaelHampton didn't know that, thanks for the info !

Comment: @Abhijeet Not to mention, you'll be on United metal, and if you do miss the flight, there are many other flights between IAH and LFT. If you miss the 15:36 flight, the next one is at 17:35, then 19:05, then 21:22.